# No queue factory has been registered for scheme 'msmq'

Tags: c#, msmq, servicebus

I'm trying to run one of the examples for Shuttle Service Bus but when it is executing the line:

```
var bus = ServiceBus
    .Create()
    .SubscriptionManager(subscriptionManager)
    .Start()
```

I'm getting an exception with the message: No queue factory has been registered for scheme 'msmq'.

The app.config has:

```
<serviceBus>
    <inbox workQueueUri="msmq://./pubsub-client-inbox-work" errorQueueUri="msmq://./shuttle-samples-error"/>
</serviceBus>
```

What I'm missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this too and fixed it by adding a reference to `Shuttle.ESB.Msmq.dll` to the client app (or the app that the exception is being thrown in). I found the answer in this CodePlex discussion: http://shuttle.codeplex.com/discussions/446244.